# GWT RPC interface issue

Tags: gwt, rpc

I have doubt on the below code..

```
@RemoteServiceRelativePath("stockPrices")
public interface StockPriceService extends RemoteService {

  StockPrice[] getPrices(String[] symbols);
}
```

Could any one explain me what is the use of `@RemoteServiceRelativePath("stockPrices")` and what name we need to give in "stockPrices" .. is it mandatory??

thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check out [documentation for RemoteServiceRelativePath annotation](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/rpc/RemoteServiceRelativePath.html), it explains pretty well what this annotation does. In your case, your service must be located at `GWT.getModuleBaseURL() + "stockPrices"` ... that means that if your GWT app is at `/mygwtapp`, then your service must be at `/mygwtapp/stockPrices`. It's up to you to install some service at this URL, usually by defining servlet implementing the service interface.

You can use any other path instead of `"stockPrices"`, just make sure there is real service behind this path on the server.

Your remote services need *some* remote path (entry point), either by using `@RemoteServiceRelativePath` annotation, or by setting it through [ServiceDefTarget interface](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/rpc/ServiceDefTarget.html). If service has no entry point, it cannot be called. (Remember: this path is URL on the server)

For example, instead of using `@RemoteServiceRelativePath`, you can define your service without this annotation, and then when you instantiate async service proxy, you explicitly set path:

```
StockPriceServiceAsync stockService = GWT.create(StockPriceService.class);
((ServiceDefTarget) stockService).setServiceEntryPoint("/services/stock.service");
```